# How to create nested structure in CQ5 dictionary?

Tags: internationalization, aem, sling

I wonder if there is a way to create nested dictionary structure, to have keys somehow name-spaced? (Without creating hundreds of dictionaries)

I have tried:

```
{
    "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
    "sling:basename": "en-content",
    "jcr:mixinTypes": ["mix:language"],
    "jcr:created": "Mon Mar 25 2013 07:00:18 GMT-0400",
    "jcr:language": "en",
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Folder",
    "test": {
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:created": "Mon Mar 25 2013 13:26:52 GMT-0400",
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:folder",
        "item": {
            "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
            "jcr:mixinTypes": ["sling:Message"],
            "jcr:created": "Mon Mar 25 2013 07:00:18 GMT-0400",
            "sling:message": "Value",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:folder"
        }
    }
}
```

but `http://localhost:4503/libs/cq/i18n/translator.html` shows only `test` entry.

I fetch CQ's dictionary directly from my JavaScript app, therefore nested JSON format would be useful for developers and content creators.

According to http://sling.apache.org/site/internationalization-support-i18n.html

> The (direct) child nodes of the mix:language node must contain two
>   special properties naming the key string and the message:

Is there any other way to get it from non-direct child, or work around it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The sample you provided will work (although I'd prefer to use nt:unstructured as nodetype for test. The only issue is you can't use CQs Translator as is since it doesn't know about the name spacing. You can extend it tho or raise a feature request to Adobe tho.

HTH,
(c)